# How to check email address from display name and email address by comma seperated is valid or not?

Tags: jquery

**How to i check email address from display name and email address by comma seperated is valid or not...**

```
"a1 b.d"<a1@test.com>,  // this is valid
<a2@test.com>,   // this is valid
"a3 b.d"<a3@test.com> , // this is valid
a b.c a4@test.com ,   // this is not valid
"a1 b.d"<a1@test.com>,  // this is valid
<a2test.com>,   // this is not valid
"a3 b.d"<a3@testcom> , // this is not valid
" a b.c a4@test.com " ,   // this is not valid
```

**if overall is valid or not? how to check?**

Comment: 1400+ reputations without a single accepted question. You must be one of a kind!!

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with all the emails then validate while looping. Check the list language construct. http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php